# Conflicts between attempted installs while installing gstreamer plugin on Centos

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, centos, plugins

I am trying to install `gstreamer-ffmpeg` package for opencv c++ coding purpose on Centos-6.7

When I type;

```
sudo yum install gstreamer-ffmpeg*
```

it gives error:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libavutil.so.50 conflicts between attempted installs of libavutil50-0.7.16-33.el6.x86_64 and ffmpeg-compat-0.6.7-1.el6.x86_64
```

However there is no such file;

```
[mg@MgCentOS Desktop]$ locate libavutil.so.50
[mg@MgCentOS Desktop]$
```

And also I cannot remove, because it is not installed;

```
[mg@MgCentOS Desktop]$ sudo yum remove libavutil*
[sudo] password for mg: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: libavutil*
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.rackdc.com
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: ftp.itu.edu.tr
 * remi-safe: rpms.remirepo.net
 * rpmforge: apt.sw.be
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: fedora.tu-chemnitz.de
 * update: mirror.rackdc.com
Package(s) libavutil* available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Could you please help me how I can solve this issue, and install gstreamer plugin?

Comment: Then try to find if you have ffmpeg-compat already installed

Comment: If you manually install some of the packages and dependencies it might work, seems like something's wrong with the packaging tho: https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=13802

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I've had the same issue installing vlc.

You can have a library installed "outside of yum", with rpm, so one should check for that too:

```
rpm -qa | grep libavutil
```

then remove if found (I had to also remove libswscale):

```
rpm -e libswscale0-0.7.16-33.el6.x86_64
rpm -e libavutil50-0.7.16-33.el6.x86_64
```

This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have libavutil50 installed? If so, try to remove it and do the installation again afterwards.

Edit:

So it looks like I didn't read the question and my previous answer is useless.

You should also check if you have installed ffmpeg-compat on your mahcine.

Comment: Did you really read my question?

Comment: Sorry :D. That was awkward (actually reading your question).